# Does Azure Automation support Write-Information?

Tags: azure, powershell, logging, azure-automation

I want to write info logs into Azure Automation job logs. I've created the simple PowerShell runbook

```
$InformationPreference = "Continue"
Write-Information "Hello info" 
Write-Verbose "Hello Verbose"
Write-Warning "Hello warning"
Write-Error "Hello error"
```

And in runbook execution All logs I see only verbose, warning and error logs

[image]

If to disable runbook Verbose logs  I see only warnings and errors. Locally it works fine but not in Azure. I've also tried `Write-Information "Hello info" -InformationAction Continue` - didn't help.

`Write-Information` appeared in PowerShell 5.0.  I've checked the PS version in Azure Automation sandbox machine by using `$PSVersionTable` - it's more than 5. So, should work.

Do you know if they support it or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write info logs into Azure Automation job logs, I suggest you use `write-output`. 
For details, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages).

I'm not sure if `write-information` is supported or not in `runbook`. I test it at my side, as well as I test the cmdlet `write-host` which is a wrapper for `write-information`. But no message output for both of them.

A [support ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22430) is raised for confirmation from MS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `write-output` has a huge drawback - you can't use it in functions which returns something. For instance `function Foo() { Write-Output 'One'; return 1 }` will return an array. And `return something` is actually translated to `write-output something; return`. So, it's very sad that AA doesn't support Info.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Automation does not fully support the Information stream at this point. PowerShell 5 support is not enough: your runbook will not fail, but Automation will not capture and store the Information stream content, and this is why you will not see it in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

I do wish Write-Information was available in Azure Automation.

Using Write-Output in a function that you want to return something else (like a Boolean) is quite problematic.